# Excel VBA - Type mismatch error (13) on a variant but only in specific cases

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic table that will feed a graph (also dynamic) with data, based on the user selection in a drop down.

The whole Idea was to color the lines according to a helper column in the table that would indicate which of the series are relevant, the rest should be in shades of grey. The table look like this:

[image]

So based on the table and the helper column (right side of filter column), I want to filter the table to get rid of the OUTs and only display the relevant items. The number of series will vary with the user selection (so far, from 2 to 5).

The code:

```
'Only display non-zero values in the chart chart
Sheets("Financials").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7
Sheets("Financials").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
        "IN"

If Sheets("Financials").Range("f99") = "" Then
    GoTo EndPie:
End If

Dim DTrow As Variant
Dim ORrow As Variant
Dim EErow As Variant
Dim OTrow As Variant
Dim IDRange As Range
Dim nSrs As Long

Set IDRange = Worksheets("Financials").Range("M99:M104")

DTrow = Application.Match("DT", IDRange, 0)
ORrow = Application.Match("Orange", IDRange, 0)
EErow = Application.Match("EE", IDRange, 0)
OTrow = Application.Match("Other", IDRange, 0)

With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart

 nSrs = Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
     Select Case nSrs
         Case Is = 1
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
         Case Is = 2
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
         Case Is = 3
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
         Case Is = 4
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
             .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(121, 121, 121)
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
             .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(121, 121, 121)
         Case Is = 5
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
             .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(121, 121, 121)
             .SeriesCollection(5).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(81, 81, 81)
             .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(241, 241, 241)
             .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 201, 201)
             .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(161, 161, 161)
             .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(121, 121, 121)
             .SeriesCollection(5).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(81, 81, 81)
     End Select

    On Error Resume Next
        .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
        .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
        .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

So what it does: 
1 - filter the OUTs from the table 
2 - define a standard grey scale for the series colors 
3 - find the values in the helper colum (such as "DT in the pic) and color their respective series

The code works fine, **but when certain items are selected, the excel crashes and I get an error**

[image]

**I don't know what is happening, because there are no explicit differences between options driving the error and the ones working fine.**

Does anybody have an idea of what I could be doing wrong here?
Thanks!

**Edit1:** Error for ORrow is `ORrow = Error 2042`

Comment: In the error line, what type of variable is ORrow? What does it resolve to when you hover the mouse over it at runtime? What happens when you use the immediate window (while in break mode) to execute that line directly, but replacing ORrow with a numeric value?

Comment: It says `ORrow = Error 2042`

Comment: @ChrisMelville, when I replace it with a numeric value, the code resumes to the next line

Comment: I've had something similar happening in an application I built, and it turned out that filtering a Table was hiding a chart, and when the chart was hidden it failed on a similar line. My solution was to clear the filter before running the code. Is there any chance your chart is not visible at the time the code executes?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is **remove (or `'` comment-out) the `On Error Resume Next` line**.  You don't even know for sure which line is causing the error yet.  When troubleshooting a problem, that should always be the first step; the next being to add `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help ensure all variables and objects are being handled properly.  If you still get the same error in the same spot, *then* we can continue troubleshooting.

Comment: @ashleedawg, the `On error resume next` part is necessary because as I mentioned in the question, I dont have all series and all coloring series in every selection, so there is an error (**EXPECTED**), the program should resume until this "coloring" routine is finished. It is always either the value of the series (**when existing**) or the error, **the issue is, for most of the times it is handling the error (induced by me) correctly**, only for some specific choices, it crashes, as described in the question.

Comment: @vferraz You could write an error handling routine instead.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, but how would this look like? I mean, as I am inducing the error in the series, the idea is to resume, wouldnt the `On Error Reume Next` be responsible for handling this?

Comment: In a standard error handling routine, you could halt execution at the time of the first handled error; check that that first handled error is, indeed, the type mismatch on that line, check that your variables are properly set up, step through execution one at a time, etc.  Right now, you have no idea what, if anything, is being skipped before getting to the Type Mismatch error that you see.

Comment: Revert back to the If Not IsError(ORrow)....wrapper for each attempt to format line as we discussed before?

Comment: @QHarr, I will try it right now

Comment: It is, I'm afraid, difficult to debug ***in absentia*** so to speak. This feels like XY problem. And that the real issue has something to do with how the data is laid out and changing. I feel like I am trying to patch a leak rather than fix it.

Comment: @QHarr  I can send you a version of the file via chat, so you can have a look at it yourself, what do you think?

Comment: I don't really want to handle a file containing code. It you send an xlsx i.e. no macros possible, and https://pastebin.com/ the code I can have a look.

Comment: @QHarr Ill send via chat then, one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whilst not ideal for now a patch, given the actual document could do with a makeover.....

`Application.Match` is either returning a number or an error depending on whether value was found. This value is then used later for setting your seriescollection formats. So, a patch is to test for whether the value is an error before trying to set as shown below.

A better solution would be a lot of work I'm afraid in terms of fixing the source code.

```
 If Not IsError(DTrow) Then
   .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
   .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
   End If
   If Not IsError(ORrow) Then
   .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
   .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
   End If
   If Not IsError(EErow) Then
   .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
   .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
   End If
   If Not IsError(OTrow) Then
   .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
   .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
   End If
```

Comment: Issue solved for now, I would like to add a special thanks to @QHarr for all the support provided!